# Daily consumption report(CSV) to monthly consumption report

Tags: c#, csv

I have a daily consumption report with huge number of rows; I want to convert this to monthly report. The CSV has following headers Material-Code, Material, date and daily consumption. Any suggestions on how this can be processed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Excel would be pretty quick to do this.
You could get it done quick and dirty manually, or setup macros to automate the process.

Comment: Need this to be automatically converted every month